# Null is not an object(evaluating 'mapView.current.animateToRegion')

Tags: react-native, google-maps, react-native-maps, use-ref

In component `Description` I have a button, when I press the button I send to `Map` component coordinates of marker:

```
   const onNavigationTap = () => {
        navigation.navigate('Map', {
            destination: data["data"].coordinates,
        });
    }
```

In component `Map` I have condition:

```
const mapView = React.createRef();
   if (route.params){
        mapView.current.animateToRegion({ 
            latitude: route.params.destination.latitude,
            longitude: route.params.destination.longitude,
            latitudeDelta: 0.4,
            longitudeDelta: 0.4,
        },1000);
    }
return (
<MapView ref={mapView} />
)
```

So when I open `Map` I want to show region near marker. I've tried to create a button on Map screen:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{
                    position: 'absolute',
                    top: '5%',
                    alignSelf: 'flex-start'
                }} onPress={animateMap}><Text>Start</Text></TouchableOpacity>
```

and then I created function:

```
const animateMap = () => {
        mapView.current.animateToRegion({ // Takes a region object as parameter
            latitude: destination.latitude,
            longitude: destination.longitude,
            latitudeDelta: 0.4,
            longitudeDelta: 0.4,
        },1000);
    }
```

And this solution with button on Map screen working fine but what I want is to animateToRegion not on button press, but when user opens the Map from `Description` component. I don't understand why in first case I got `Null is not an object(evaluating 'mapView.current.animateToRegion')`. Please tell me what should I do if I want to animateToRegion using params that I get from another component?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the error you got is because `mapView.current.animateToRegion` is null.

You can follow this [sample code](https://snack.expo.dev/-PTPLAW5F) and code snippet below on how to achieve your use case:

App.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import MapScreen from './Map'

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {

const onBtnPress = () =>{
  navigation.navigate('Maps', {
            destination: { latitude: 40.463667, longitude: -3.74922 },
        });
}
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={onBtnPress}
      />
    </View>
  );
}


const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Maps" component={MapScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Map.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import MapView, { Marker, Circle, Polyline } from 'react-native-maps';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
  },
});

function Map (props){
const onMapLoad=()=>{
  console.log(this.mapView)
  console.log(props.route.params.destination.latitude)

  this.mapView.animateToRegion({ 
            latitude: props.route.params.destination.latitude,
            longitude: props.route.params.destination.longitude,
            latitudeDelta: 0.4,
            longitudeDelta: 0.4,
        },1000);

}
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
         ref={(ref) => this.mapView = ref}
          style={styles.map}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
          }}
        onMapReady={onMapLoad}
          >
       
        </MapView>
      </View>
    );
  }
 export default Map;
```